# DocumentDB, How to work with continuationToken in a SP

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

The next SP suppose to run over the collection and keep query for the next batch of documents (10 docs every batch). but instead return the same 10 documents every time.

```
function sample(prefix) {
var continuations = [],
ids = [],
 context = getContext(),
     collection = context.getCollection(),
     response = context.getResponse();
var queryOptions = { pageSize: 10, continuation: null };

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // get all user wish list actions
    var query = "select * from w",
    accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query, queryOptions, processMultiUsers);
    if (!accept) throw "Unable to read user's sessions";
}
getContext().getResponse().setBody(ids);


function processMultiUsers(err, docs, options) {
    if (err) throw new Error("Error: " + err.message);
    if (docs == undefined || docs.length == 0) throw new Error("Warning: Users not exists");

    for (j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
        ids.push(docs[j].UserId);
    }
    queryOptions.continuation = options.continuation;
    continuations.push(options.continuation);
}}
```

Comment: Take a peek at the answer I just wrote to your count question and see if that answers your question. Alternatively, you can study how this works: https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/countDocuments.coffee or come back here and ask any question that isn't answered in the other question and I'll be glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script that you wrote, the execution of the queries are done synchronously and they are queued up with the same initial continuation token, which is null. Instead, we need to take the token from the first query and then queue the next and continue.

The below sample should help achieve what you are looking for

```
function sample(continuationToken) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var maxResult = 10;
    var documentsProcessed = 0;
    var ids = [];
    var filterQuery = "select * from w";

    tryQuery(continuationToken);

    function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
        var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize: maxResult };
        if (documentsProcessed >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
            setBody(nextContinuationToken);
        }
    }

    function query(responseOptions) {
        return (filterQuery && filterQuery.length) ?
            collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments) :
            collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
    }

    function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
        }

        documentsProcessed += docFeed.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < documentsProcessed; i++) {
            ids.push(docFeed[i].UserId);
        }

        if (responseOptions.continuation) {
            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
        } else {
            setBody(null);
        }
    }

    function setBody(continuationToken) {
        var body = { continuationToken: continuationToken, documentsProcessed: documentsProcessed, ids: ids };
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Shireesh, that does the work. though I don't understand why do you put the same variable "maxResult" for what seems two different things. one is the size of each request I want to pull, the other is the limit of documents I  want to pull in total.

Comment: @GuyAssaf - maxResult is primarily intended to control the overall document count in the final response, but it can also be used to set it as page size to be the maximum results requested for each round trip. When you set a pageSize = 'x', the promise is that the roundtrip will get atmost (<=) x results. So, by  using the same value, we are trying to minimize the number of roundtrips as much as possible.

Comment: You mean that if there is a limit to the amount of documents I want to process then it's better to request the page size with the same amount, so not to request twice ?  What then if there is no max results, I need all ?

Comment: @GuyAssaf exactly. Asking for the same limit minimizes the overall number of requests. If you need all, set this option to -1.